# Terraform, weird patterns in the log [32m+ [0m

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-terraform-cloudbuild-gitops) from the official GCP repo on how to deploy terraform from a cloud build:

**cloudbuils.yaml**

```yaml
steps:
- id: 'branch name'
  name: 'alpine'
  entrypoint: 'sh'  
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      echo "***********************"
      echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
      echo "***********************"
- id: 'tf init'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:1.0.0'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - |
      if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
        cd environments/$BRANCH_NAME
        terraform init
      else
        for dir in environments/*/
        do 
          cd ${dir}   
          env=${dir%*/}
          env=${env#*/}
          echo ""
          echo "*************** TERRAFORM INIT ******************"
          echo "******* At environment: ${env} ********"
          echo "*************************************************"
          terraform init || exit 1
          cd ../../
        done
      fi
```

and I am having the following pattern in the log:

```sh
2022-02-21 07:13:13.094 CETStep #3 - "tf apply": [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0munique_id[0m[0m = (known after apply)
2022-02-21 07:13:13.094 CETStep #3 - "tf apply": }
2022-02-21 07:13:13.094 CETStep #3 - "tf apply":
2022-02-21 07:13:13.094 CETStep #3 - "tf apply": [0m[1mPlan:[0m 7 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Which makes the debug a lot more painful that it needs to be, I am sure it is a simple formatting issue, but I could not find its origin.

Comment: Add `-no-color` to `terraform` commands and see if that helps.

Comment: Sadly, no effect :(

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar issue occur in the [link1](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin/issues/145#issuecomment-916164416), [link2](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3278#issuecomment-141497096) and [link3](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12305#issuecomment-283282913) where it has been mentioned that :

> Apparently Terraform attempts to format the output using color. However, Jenkins does not output this formatting correctly and thus you see those unusual characters in the output.
> was able to make Terraform omit those characters in the output by using the -no-color flag.
> This option is available for at least three of the major Terraform functions: show, plan, and apply.
> It resolved by using `terraform show -no-color`

For more information on how to manage infrastructure as code with terraform, cloud build and gitops, you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/managing-infrastructure-as-code).